# How to check if a number is in a range?

Tags: bash

For a program I am writing, I need to read a value from a file. When I do that, I get a value in the form `(x, y)`. I need to make a script that splits those, so `$x` is the `x value` and `$y` is the `y value`.

Then, I need to do a check. For example, check if `$x` is in between `$x-max` and `$x-min`, with `$x-max` and `$x-min` being integers.

Comment: What do you mean by "give the user a range"? To give them some information about this string, to check this string, or to tell them the range of possible numbers in the string?

Comment: Please re-write your question to remove all the irrelevant stuff about tablets, google searches, accelerometers, etc, and just ask a concise question about what you want. I have the same question as l0b0 - your actual question is very short and vague.

Comment: Edited. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split the string into two numbers:

```
$ foo="(506,-664)"
$ declare -a bar=${foo//,/ }
$ for integer in ${bar[@]}
> do
>     echo "$integer"
> done
506
-664
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I need! Is there any way from there to split the two numbers?

Comment: err nvm I used echo $integer and got them on one line.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm taking this in all wrong, I'd imagine you just need to process the string and derive the numerical components. Just scan the string until the "," character (for the x) then scan from the first character after the comma to the end for the y.

Answer (score 0):

After a ton of searching, I finally found my answer. I guess I wasn't looking hard enough. For anyone who has a similar problem to me, the code is:

if bar.txt contains (x,y),

$cat /foo/bar.txt | tr -d "()" | sed 's/,/ /g' | cut -d" " -f1
x
$cat /foo/bar.txt | tr -d "()" | sed 's/,/ /g' | cut -d" " -f2
y

I'm sure there's a much less messy way to do this, but this got me the results i needed.